# Saving each of this boards into a Data Structure

Tags: java, readfile

This is a dumb question and I feel embarrassed to ask it, but I'm pressed for time and I'm burnt out.

I have this sample input:

```
1 4 2
3 0 5
6 7 8

3 1 2
6 4 5
0 7 8

-1 -1 -1
```

Each group of numbers represents a board of the 8 puzzle, I don't know how many boards will appear on the text file. I only know its end is marked with -`1 -1 -1.`

I know the logic for this thing is simple, I'm just tired and can't put the code to work.

The output for the first board should be:

```
142305678
```

and for the second one

```
312645078
```

I'm getting:

```
142142142 
312312312
```

Here's my code so far:

```
package puzzle;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Main {



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */





    public static void saveTheLine (String [] splittedLine ) {


            }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // TODO code application logic here

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("E://Documents and Settings//Administrator//My Documents//NetBeansProjects//8Puzzle//src//puzzle//ocho.in");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);


  /*
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (!line.equals("-1 -1 -1")) {


        line= br.readLine();
         //ArrayList <String> board = new ArrayList<String>();


              String board = new String("");
               while (!line.equals(null))
                {

                   board = board + line;
                   line= br.readLine();

               }

                System.out.println("a board is " + board);

            }

*/




    while (true) {

        String line= br.readLine();
        if (!line.equals("-1 -1 -1")){

            if (line.equals(" ")) {
                continue;
            }


            String board = new String (" ");

            ArrayList<String> board2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i =0; i<3; i++){

                String [] splittedLine = line.split(" ");
                board = line+board;

                for (int addToBoardIndex =0; addToBoardIndex < splittedLine.length; addToBoardIndex++){

                    board2.add(splittedLine[addToBoardIndex]);
                }
                br.readLine();



            }

            //System.out.println(board);

            for (String s : board2) {
                System.out.print(s);
            }

            System.out.println(" ");

        }

        else if (line.equals("-1 -1 -1")) {
                break;
            }
    }


    /*String line = br.readLine();




    while (!line.equals("-1 -1 -1"))

    {


        //StringBuilder board = new StringBuilder("");

        ArrayList<String> board = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int lineIndex =0; lineIndex<3; lineIndex++){

            line = br.readLine();
            String [] splittedLine = line.split(" ");
            board.add(splittedLine [0]);
            board.add(splittedLine [1]);
            board.add(splittedLine [2]);


        }




         for (String boardIndex: board){
             System.out.println(boardIndex);
         }



         String blankLine = br.readLine();





     }*/
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What type of output are you getting and what type do you expect? And what's the point in posting (let alone having) commented out code or empty methods?

Comment: Well, for one, you might want your blank line check to be: if(line.trim().equals("")) instead of if(line.equals(" ")).

Comment: Regarding trim: that will allow you to check for a blank line that contains any amount of whitespace (including no whitespace), your current check looks for a line with exactly one space on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ...
> br.readLine();
> ...
> ```

You call `readLine()`, but you don't actually assign it to `line` or do anything else with it. Thus you keep re-using the first line over and over.